# Capture and encode HDMI signal on FreeBSD

Tags: hdmi, streaming, freebsd, h.264

I am looking for a capture PCI-e card to encode HDMI source and stream on network. I want to "share" my HDMI sources to my Raspberry sinks in the LAN.

I have found many PCI-e cards, but most of them supported only on Windows, some on Linux, none of them in FreeBSD.

Does anybody have experience with a capture card with HDMI in, h/w based h264 encoder which works on FreeBSD?

Answer (score 0):

The [webcamd](http://www.selasky.org/hans_petter/video4bsd/) software is a [port](http://www.freshports.org/multimedia/webcamd/) of the Linux USB device drivers for webcams and DVB devices into userspace on FreeBSD.

There is a good chance you'd be able to grab video with that. Not sure if those would support hardware encoding, though.